# Skip a specifc iteration of an Ansible loop given a condition

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm attempting to skip an Ansible loop iteration when a specific variable is passed onto the playbook.

I have the following `with_items:` on an ansible task:

```
...
...

with_items:
        - "item1"
        - "{{ 'item2' if my_env != 'my_env_1' }}"
```

I want the playbook to skip that second item completely and do nothing when `my_env == 'my_env_1'`

The above snippet seemed to make sense to me, however when I run the playbook I get the following error:

`fatal: [...]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the inline if-expression on line 1 evaluated to false and no else section was defined."}`

My else statement would be wanting the playbook to skip it. Is there any way to specify that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: ***"Skip second item in the loop when `my_env == 'my_env_1'`"***

A: For example, use *ternary* and *flatten* the list

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ my_list|flatten }}"
      vars:
        my_list:
          - item1
          - "{{ (my_env == 'my_env_1')|ternary([], 'item2') }}"
          - item3
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_env=my_env_1

...

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=item1) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item1
ok: [localhost] => (item=item3) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item3
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_env=my_env_X

...

TASK [debug] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=item1) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item1
ok: [localhost] => (item=item2) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item2
ok: [localhost] => (item=item3) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: item3
```